# Extract word form string using regex word boundaries in python

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have such a file name and I want to extract part of it as a string in Python

```
import re
fn = "DC_QnA_bo_v.15.12.3_DE_duplicates.xlsx"
rgx = re.compile('\b_[A-Z]{2}\b')
print(re.findall(rgx, fn))
```

Expected out put `[DE]`, but actual out is `[]`.

Comment: A `_` is a word character, so `\b` won't work

Comment: Try `_([A-Z]{2})` instead with a capturing group

Comment: `rgx = re.compile('_([A-Z]{2})')`?

Comment: What is the condition' so yoe want to get 'DE' and not 'DC'?

Comment: Just `re.findall(r'_([A-Z]{2})_', fn)` will do, no need for any lookarounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
(?<=_)[A-Z]+(?=_)
```

This makes use of lookarounds on both sides, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/R80ggF/1/). For tighter results, you'd need to specify more sample inputs though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `_([A-Z]{2})`

**Ex:**

```
import re
fn = "DC_QnA_bo_v.15.12.3_DE_duplicates.xlsx"
rgx = re.compile('_([A-Z]{2})')
print(rgx.findall(fn))           #You can use the compiled pattern to do findall.
```

**Output:**

```
['DE']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output seems to be `DE` which is in bounded with two `_` from left and right. This expression might also work:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re

string = "DC_QnA_bo_v.15.12.3_DE_duplicates.xlsx"
expression = r'_([A-Z]+)_'
match = re.search(expression, string)
if match:
    print("YAAAY! \"" + match.group(1) + "\" is a match  ")
else: 
    print(' Sorry! No matches!')
```

#### Output

```
YAAAY! "DE" is a match
```

Or you can add a `2` quantifier, if you might want:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re

string = "DC_QnA_bo_v.15.12.3_DE_duplicates.xlsx"
expression = r'_([A-Z]{2})_'
match = re.search(expression, string)
if match:
    print("YAAAY! \"" + match.group(1) + "\" is a match  ")
else: 
    print(' Sorry! No matches!')
```

[image]

### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Rm50Ir/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try pattern: `\_([^\_]+)\_[^\_\.]+\.xlsx`

Explanation:

`\_` - match `_` literally

`[^\_]+` - negated character class with `+` operator: match one or more times character other than `_`

`[^\_\.]+` - same as above, but this time match characters other than `_` and `.`

`\.xlsx` - match `.xlsx` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fFfV1S/1)

The idea is to match last pattern `_something_` before extension `.xlsx`

Answer (score 0):

Another `re` solution:

```
rgx = re.compile('_([A-Z]{1,})_')
print(re.findall(rgx, fn))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expression (`re` module) for that as already shown, however this could be done without using any `import`s, following way:

```
fn = "DC_QnA_bo_v.15.12.3_DE_duplicates.xlsx"
out = [i for i in fn.split('_')[1:] if len(i)==2 and i.isalpha() and i.isupper()]
print(out) # ['DE']
```

Explanation: I split `fn` at `_` then discard 1st element and filter elements so only `str`s of length 2, consisting of letters and consisting of uppercases remain.